# Particles not piling up at end of curve

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

I have a particle system following a curve and hitting a collision plane at the end. The particles are supposed to pile up at the end of the curve, simulating sand blowing in the wind, however they are heading off into -y direction. Any ideas on how to get them to pile up when they hit the collision plane?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image that shows your particle / collision settings?

Comment: Here are the requested settings

Comment: Perhaps the particles are going too fast and teleporting past the plane? Try adding subframes in the particle physics panel.